# Having deadlock with simple nodejs task

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

**Hi team**, *I have a simple nodeJS program below*

- I have created this file in Amazon server and i am accessing it
  through ssh from terminal
- this program runs fine but if i try to access from iphone browser (i
  mean the output of ththis program running on aws server ) i cant

---

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});
server.listen(8000);
```

Do some specific configuration need to be made on server, or the program

i `am typing the url as http://serveraddress:8000/ from phone browser`

Comment: What browser is returning - is it idling to load, or it throwing some error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have allowed traffic through port 8000 in Firewall (AWS EC2 Security Group) settings in AWS EC2 Management Console.

Comment: please can u tell me how to enable this security feature in AWS EC2 ?

Comment: Go to AWS Management Console > EC2 > Network & Security > Security Groups > select your group > Inbound (tab) > Type port in "port range" > Add Rule > Apply Rule Changes